# Create an array of object PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create this structure on PHP

[image]

and I don't know how to I create an array of object on PHP. It always get the last data from the object.

This is my current code:

```
array(
     "description": getDescription($id),
     "deposit": getPrices($id);
)


function getPrices($id) {
    $test = Prices::where('price_id',$id)->where('promo',0)->get();
    $price = [];
    $data = [];

    foreach($test as $t) {
        $data["item_id"] = $t->id;
        $data["price"] = $t->list;
        $data["type"] = $t->type;

        $price = $data;
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Comment: you should declare array vars like `'key' => $value`

Comment: `$price[] = $data;`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixing the actual issue with not receiving all records from the `getPrices` function:**

```
array(
     "description": getDescription($id),
     "deposit": getPrices($id);
)


function getPrices($id) {
    $test = Prices::where('price_id',$id)->where('promo',0)->get();
    $price = [];        

    foreach($test as $t) {            
        $price[] = ["item_id" => $t->id, "price" => $t->list, "type": $t->type];
    }

    return $price;
}
```

You're missing the square brackets after `$price` (Correct: `$price[]`) variable which tells PHP to append to array rather than actually replace it.

The other option is to use `array_push`, which is more explicit but does the same; Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

**Fixing the issue of serialisation:**

You can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to serialise the array into JSON (**J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation).

Comment: Thanks for explaining this part:

Comment: I've added some changes if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataArray=array(); 
 foreach($test as $t) {
      $dataArray[] = array('item'=> $t->id,'item'=> $t->price,'type'=> $t->type);
 }
 $finalArray= array('deposit'=>$dataArray);
```

convert final array to json using `json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

```
$structure = new stdClass();

$structure->description = 'tobedefined'; // Define the description here
$structure->deposit = getPrices($id);

function getPrices($id) {
    $deposits = array();

    // Change this to contain the real data
    // $test = Prices::where('price_id',$id)->where('promo',0)->get();
    $test = array(
        array(
            'item_id' => 100,
            'price' => '1, 2, 3, 4, 5',
            'type' => 'child'
        ),
        array(
            'item_id' => 101,
            'price' => '2, 4, 6, 8, 10',
            'type' => 'child'
        ),
        array(
            'item_id' => 102,
            'price' => '2, 4, 6, 8, 10',
            'type' => 'child'
        )
    );

    foreach ($test as $t) {
        $deposit = new stdClass();

        $deposit->item_id = $t['item_id'];
        $deposit->price = $t['price'];
        $deposit->type = $t['type'];

        $deposits[] = $deposit;
    }
    return $deposits;
}

echo 'PHP Structure';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($structure);
echo '</pre>';

echo 'JSON string';
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_encode($structure, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output will be:**

PHP Structure

```
stdClass Object
(
    [description] => tobedefined
    [deposit] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [item_id] => 100
                    [price] => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
                    [type] => child
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [item_id] => 101
                    [price] => 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
                    [type] => child
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [item_id] => 102
                    [price] => 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
                    [type] => child
                )

        )

)
```

JSON string

```
{
    "description": "tobedefined",
    "deposit": [
        {
            "item_id": 100,
            "price": "1, 2, 3, 4, 5",
            "type": "child"
        },
        {
            "item_id": 101,
            "price": "2, 4, 6, 8, 10",
            "type": "child"
        },
        {
            "item_id": 102,
            "price": "2, 4, 6, 8, 10",
            "type": "child"
        }
    ]
}
```